# PouchDB has documents that are 'undefined' instead of just {} or {_id}. How do I delete them?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, couchdb, pouchdb

My `pouchdb-find` queries are failing because there are some bad data objects: they are `undefined`, actually stored `undefined`s in the database. They are not `{}` or {`_id: 'something'}`, they are actually `undefined`s.

## Details

I discovered it while trying to query for a field being not-null. When I query for `{$eq: null}` to find those records, I found something strange.

Query:

```js
await db.find({ selector: {text: {$gt: null}} });
// or
await db.find({ selector: {text: {$exists: true}} });
```

Results:

```json
{
  docs: [
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    {
      _id: 'test-id-1618443059797',
      _rev: '3-251568304e939d8d5b688af8c09eaa13'
    },
    {
      _id: 'test-id-1618443082960',
      _rev: '3-a60c1dde0e11e14d0a14cd86d2478140'
    }
  ]
}
```

This seems to explain why I'm getting errors like the following. (The slightly different formatting is from `tslog`).

```
TypeError  Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
error stack:
• index.js:14 getFieldFromDoc
    node_modules/.pnpm/pouchdb-selector-core@7.2.2/node_modules/pouchdb-selector-core/lib/index.js:14:18

• index.js:345 <anonymous>
    node_modules/.pnpm/pouchdb-selector-core@7.2.2/node_modules/pouchdb-selector-core/lib/index.js:345:25

• index.js:342 rowFilter
    node_modules/.pnpm/pouchdb-selector-core@7.2.2/node_modules/pouchdb-selector-core/lib/index.js:342:25

• index.js:319 <anonymous>
    node_modules/.pnpm/pouchdb-selector-core@7.2.2/node_modules/pouchdb-selector-core/lib/index.js:319:12

• index.js:318 filterInMemoryFields
    node_modules/.pnpm/pouchdb-selector-core@7.2.2/node_modules/pouchdb-selector-core/lib/index.js:318:15

• index.js:1307 <anonymous>
    node_modules/.pnpm/pouchdb-find@7.2.2/node_modules/pouchdb-find/lib/index.js:1307:40
```

The same kind of error happens for other queries involving fields, since `null.<anything>` will keep causing errors like that.

---

### What I think is going on

I figure these are corrupted writes, and I'm trying to figure out how to clean those up without doing a `destroy()`. The state seems corrupt overall because there are multiple of these `undefined` records.

### What I've tried

- Thoroughly debugging, through the library code. Helped me clarify the issue but I don't have a fix yet.
- For good measure, I tried each way to delete a record [detailed in the PouchDB docs](https://pouchdb.com/guides/updating-deleting.html). They hit the same error (which makes sense to me)

  - Because they are `undefined`, I cannot set `_deleted` property. And even if I could change properties, there's no `_id` to pass to `remove` etc.
- Working around with `.destroy()`, i.e. loading data from `allDocs`, calling `destroy`, and putting it all back. This seems hacky because more data corruption could happen in the process.

#### Environment

My current usage is in a nodejs environment. Executing via `ts-node` but I doubt that matters.

#### Dependency versions

```
pouchdb 7.2.2
pouchdb-find 7.2.2
```

---

### How do I remove these `undefined` documents?

Is there any way to handle this besides destroying? (Meaning, I would copy the data out, destroy, then put all the non-corrupt data back; but that could cause new issues

Comment: Whether it's actually a corrupted write, or just an erroneous return value from a query, it sounds like a bug, and probably worth bringing up on the [PouchDB issue tracker](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues).

Comment: Have you tried replicating the database? It would be interesting to see if any troublesome documents land in the replicated db.

Comment: @Flimzy good call, I'll do that!

Comment: @RamblinRose, that's a good point, I'll try that!

Comment: Hello @m_floer !
I got the same problem. How did you solve this ?

Comment: @IlyaIuyeu I didn't find a solution unfortunately. I ended up migrating away from PouchDB. I've been using [Dexie.js](https://dexie.org/).